# Populating new numpy array with another's values in for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I'm doing something stupid with `numpy`. Trying to populate one `numpy` array with values from another via a for loop, like this:

```
for i in range(0,9998):
    a[i] = b[i] * c[i]
```

I'm getting the following error:

> "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment"

Btw I need this loop (as opposed to just multiplying the arrays without indexes) because b and c are longer arrays then I want a to be, and I couldn't find an elegant way of making numpy arrays shorter. Thanks in advance for advice!

Comment: If `b` and `c` are longer than you want `a` to be, wouldn't a slice be appropriate? It might help to give more information about what you're trying to do here. Can you provide the full Traceback?

Comment: How did you initial `a`?

Comment: Maybe 'a' is already defined as a numpy.float64

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply slices of b and c. That is,

```
a = b[:9999] * c[:9999]
```

Will multiply the first 9999 items from `b` by the first 9999 items from `c` and store the values in an array of length 9999 referenced by `a`.

If `a` is an existing array that you want to assign specific values to, you instead need to do

```
a[:9999] = b[:9999] * c[:9999]
```

Comment: actually to do what the OP showed you need to do ``a[:9999] = b[:9999] * c[:9999]``. Otherwise it will just create a new ``a`` and "delete" the old one. But I guess that's what is producing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are doing something like this:

```
In [281]: a=np.float64(0)

In [282]: a[0]=2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-282-ed5200211ec0> in <module>()
----> 1 a[0]=2

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment
```

You need to start with something like

```
a = np.zeros(10000,), dtype=float)
```

if you want that sort of loop to work.